# Get Records with both matching values in SQL

Tags: sql

Table A

```
id1 | id2     |
---------------
2  |    3     |
4  |    5     |
```

Table B

```
groupid | parentid | uid
    ----------------
    4   | 2 (id1) |  1
    4   | 3 (id2) |  2
    6   | 2       |  3
    7   | 4 (Id1) |  4
    8   | 4 (Id1) |  5
    8   | 5 (Id2) |  6
    8   | 6       |  7
```

I want to fetch records where groupid should have both id1 & id2.

So in this case uid 1,2 & 5,6 should be retrieved because groupid 4 & 8 have both of them.

How to achieve this in SQL? By SQL, let's say SQL Server

Comment: The `(id1)` and `(id2)` is part of the `parentId` column?

Comment: also why `uid=7` is not fetched since `groupid=8` has both?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Ya. That's also should not be included although it is part of group. But that should not be in selection of uid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
select distinct B1.uid from TableB B1
join TableB B2 on B1.groupid = B2.groupid and B1.parentid ! = B2.parentid
and (
    (B1.parentid in (select id1 from TableA) AND B2.parentid in (select id2 from TableA))
    OR
    (B2.parentid in (select id1 from TableA) AND B1.parentid in (select id2 from TableA))
    )
```

Test it here:
http://rextester.com/KZY45975

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select b.uid from TableB b inner join TableA a on (a.id1 = b.parentid) inner join TableB c on (c.parentid = a.id2 and c.uid = b.uid)
```

might returns what you want